# Apply a git stash with the orignal timestamps

Tags: git

It seems that `git stash pop` gives every file it lays down a current timestamp.  Can this be avoided?  I want the re-applied files to have their original timestamps, at least for files that weren't changed since they were stashed.

Comment: Just to add to @matt's answer, you probably don't really want to do that. Git resets the timestamp every time a file is modified on your filesystem due to a Git action, which is what you want if you're using a build system. Every time you stash, unstash, checkout a different branch, etc, the next `make all` will probably have to rebuild anything that depends on the files that operation touched. Otherwise, `git stash; make all; git stash pop; make all` might keep a stale build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that this has anything to do with `stash`. No "timestamps" are being stored; it's just that certain acts that you perform with Git create files. You can get the same effect by switching to another branch, then immediately switching back to the first branch. All the files in your working tree that are under Git control will have their dates set to now, because Git just "created" them — that's what switching to a branch means.